# requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.glass;

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

I have tried to install and run the compass sample project from

glass developers site.

I get the following error

when try installing on non-rooted devices (nexsus4, galaxy note2):

`requires unavailable shared library com.google.android.glass; failing!`

I have tried to remove this from the manifest,

but now the apk seems to be installed but nothing is really added to the device

```
[2014-01-21 15:29:33 - compassApp] Uploading compassApp.apk onto device '4df1250c1d449f4d'
[2014-01-21 15:29:33 - compassApp] Installing compassApp.apk...
[2014-01-21 15:29:46 - compassApp] Success!
[2014-01-21 15:29:46 - compassApp] /compassApp/bin/compassApp.apk installed on device
[2014-01-21 15:29:46 - compassApp] Done!
```

Comment: You are trying to deploy glassware to an Android phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can't run glassware on a standard Android device.

Hence glassware requires api's found only in Google glass

---

I found a [workaround](http://www.elekslabs.com/2013/11/google-glass-development-without-glass.html) to run glassware on an Android device. This will add the required api's to your Android device through apk's. Haven't tried it myself.

---